# Counting FPS using SELENIUM

Tags: selenium-webdriver, metrics, frame-rate

I want to make a program that will count FPS in real time from a web application running in a browser. On pyppeteer (not pup), it turned out to do this as follows: I started writing to a file the events that occur on the page, among which there are "drawFrame" events. Next, I summarize all such events and divide by the time of collecting events, thereby obtaining fps.
But I have a need to do this in selenium.
I searched the Internet for information about this, but I only found something about how to calculate iframes, which is not the same.
How to calculate fps in a program using selenium (and if possible python)?

Comment: I think Chrome's dev tools might already have this, so look into getting it from there.  https://devtoolstips.org/tips/en/display-current-framerate/